# Trim and reuse RegExp matches to update string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a method to  remove the extra spaces between words and trim start and end of strings:

```js
// Remove extra spaces between words and trim start and end of strings
String.prototype.trimmer = function() {
  return String(this).replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, '');
};

const text = "    This ,           is!! !not ??trimmed::  :: correctly .   . .      ";

console.log(text.trimmer());
```

Now the issue is how we can put each of these signs `, ! ? : .` to be right after the previous word and without any space.

**So the desired result for the given text would be:**

```
This, is!!! not?? trimmed:::: correctly...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look for all the signs `, ! ? : .` (including spaces). Then use those "matches" to replace all spaces and only add one at the end. Not sure if you could achieve the same result with a single Regex. Like so it works.

```js
String.prototype.trimmer = function() {
  return String(this).replace(
    /([\.\,\!\:\? ]+)/g,
    function(match){
      return match.replace(/ /g, '') + ' ';
    }
  ).trim() // remove spaces at beginning and end of string
};

const text = "    This ,           is!! !not ??trimmed::  :: correctly .   . .      ";

console.log(text.trimmer());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve that with a series of regex replaces:

```js
function trimText(str) {
  return str
  .replace(/\s+([,!?:\.]+)/g, '$1')          // trim leading spaces from punctuation
  .replace(/([,!?:\.])(?![,!?:\.])/g, '$1 ') // add a space after last punctuation
  .replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')                    // remove excessive spaces
  .trim()                                    // trim leading & trailing spaces
}

const text = "    This ,           is!! !not ??trimmed::  :: correctly .   . .      ";

console.log('==>' + trimText(text) + '<==');
```

Output:

```
==>This, is!!! not?? trimmed:::: correctly...<==
```